# React.js click event no response for the first click

Tags: list, reactjs, mobile, click

this is a spa on ios,click event no response for the first click,when i clicked it once later,it works fine.
this is my code:
on parent component:

```
handleSelectMonth (selectedMonth) {
    alert(selectedMonth);
}
```

this method is defined on parent component,the method render on parent component:

```
<Months handleSelectMonth={this.handleSelectMonth.bind(this)}/>
```

the children component:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className="m-months">
            {
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].map((val, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <ul className="months">
                                {
                                    val.data.map((val, index) => {
                                        return <li key={index} onClick={this.props.handleSelectMonth.bind(this, index)}></li>
                                    })
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The issue might be caused by the CSS of your component. Try to remove the styling and check if the problem is still present.

Comment: thank you,i use the event touchstart & touchend replaced the event click,but below ios 9,it  comes again.maybe it caused by the css,i will check it without the styling.